How to make a migration to an existing Postgresql database?
I'm using .NET 8, Visual Studio 2022, Clean Architecture, DDD, EF Core, postgresql.
I have these 4 layers: Infrastructure, Application, Domain, Presentation
I have defined my entities in the domain layer. Let's call them A, B and C.
I have created configurations in the infrastructure layer inheriting from IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>.
I can build and add a migration successfully in my infrastructure layer.
Here is my concern:
I'm connecting to an existing Postgresql database with an existing table that my application is built around to read from. I have defined the content of the existing table as an entity (A) in my domain layer.
How can I create new tables wit my other entities (B and C) while Entity Framework understands that A has an existing table that I only want to read from?
Please ask for further details if I have not expressed myself clearly.
Thank you!
My first migrations seems to want to create a new table
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
     name: "TransferMessages",
     columns: table => new

How do I point to the existing table so it knows that it is there?

should i maybe have scaffolded the model from the database first and added the new entities afterwards?

I would go this way:

Create an initial migration only with your Entity A and your DbSet<A>.
Delete all Code which is in the Up() and Down() methods in your
initial migration.
Update database with dotnet-ef tool.
Now you have still one Table A in your database, but EF knows how to handle this table.
Introduce Entities B and C with DbSet<B> and DbSet<C>.
Add a Second migration.
Update database with dotnet-ef tool again.

Now you have 3 Tables in the database and everything should work now.

Are you suggesting creating a new table "A"?
Entity A should be a model of the data from the existing table, not a base for a new table.

No, your Table A still remains in the database. You have your Entity A in your code. Then you create a Initial migration. Then you delete the UP and DOWN statements and then you update the database (nothing will change in den database except you will have one entry in the new migration table). Then just execute the steps I have posted. :)
